# How can I select specific fields using the firestore modular api

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

In the <= V8 Firestore API I could query a set of documents and extract a subset of fields with code like the following:

```
  const membersRef = db.collection('members');
  const snapshot = await membersRef.select('First', 'Last').get();
```

With the new modular api I can do the following:

```
import { collection } from 'firebase/firestore';
const membersRef = collection(db,'members');
// how to select only First and Last from members ?
```

I can't find a select() function to specify fields in the new api.  How can this be done using the V9 modular api?

I know I can read the entire collection and use .map()/.forEach to reduce the fields but I have some large fields I would rather not query unless I need them for a specific document.  The use of select to have the server pull out only the fields needed is useful.

Comment: Given that you're using `select`, I assume you're using the Firebase Admin SDK and Node.js and updated the tags to reflect that.

Comment: I still see `select` in the latest version of the GCP Node.js SDK, which is what the Firebase Admin SDK wraps: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#select

Comment: The new 'modular' api uses a function oriented approach instead of the chaining methods.  Highlights here - https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade.  My particular interest at the moment is via the web api but I understand it also works on the backend.

Comment: The web API never had a `select` method, neither in v8 or before nor in v9 or later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client-side SDKs for Firebase don't have a `select` method/function, but always retrieve full documents. So the `select` method didn't exist in the v8 [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference) or [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Query) classes, nor does it exist as a top-level function in the v9 modular SDK.

There *is* a `select()` method in the Admin SDK for Node.js, but that one still works as a [method on CollectionRefence](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#select) as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ahh, you are quite correct.  I had been using the admin api with select thinking it was the web api.  Thanks for setting me straight.